# How can I reference my own table with the MVC Controller.User property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, asp.net-membership

With the default membership provider for MVC 2 projects, I can reference `User.Identity.UserName` as per whatever it creates by default. I don't want to do this--want to use my own tables. So, I implemented the System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider class. The only thing I've implemented, as per many posts on the web and SO, is `ValidateUser(string username, string password)`

I can easily see this accepts username and password strings, I access my database context (LINQ to Entities, actually the dotConnect provider for MySQL), and check the username and password--simple enough.

But, how can I make the Controller.User object use the properties of my own table. For example, my table is called Staff. It has StaffID (PK), FirstName, LastName, etc. How can I access the StaffID of the current contextual user as follows?

```
int id = User.StaffID;
```

I found this post by Matt Wrock, but I can't really make sense of implementing the User class, specifically the IsInRole method. When is this object constructed, and where do the constructor arguments come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the Membership provider so I try to avoid dealing with it at all cost. In case you rather not use the `User` from the controller, you can do the following.

Create a base controller and have all your controllers inherit from it.

In your base controller, add a property called `CurrentUser` of whatever type you want to use (probably Linq 2 Sql type).

Override the `Initialize` method on your base controller and run the logic to get the proper user if the user is authenticated. Set `CurrentUser` to the proper user. Now you have access to that property in any controller that inherits from your base controller.

```
public BaseController : Controller
{
     public MyUserEntity CurrentUser {get; set;}

     protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
     {
            CurrentUser = null;
            if (requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userRepository = new UserRepository();
                CurrentUser = userRepository.GetUser(requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            }

     }

}
```

And to use it:

```
public StaffController : BaseController
{
      public ActionResult View()
      {
           var staffRepository = new StaffRepository();
           var staff = staffRepository(CurrentUser.StaffID);
           return View(staff);
      }
}
```

Comment: I love the idea of not using the MembershipProvider, but I'm confused by "of whatever type you want to use (probably Linq 2 Sql type)." Are there data provider user types provided? Or is this a custom class? Fortunately, I already have a base controller in place to handle some custom exceptions.

Comment: It is a custom class. In my application I have a `Users` table and use Linq2SQL to generate classes. I use the `User` class that Linq2SQL generates for the `CurrentUser` property.

Comment: I think I follow. My users are in the Staff table. So the CurrentUser property you used above should be of type Staff, right?

Comment: @David - Yes, if that's how you identify registered users.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do quite a bit if you want to get that to work.

you'll need to define your own class that descend from

```
GenericIdentity
```

Next you'll need define your own class that descends from

```
GenericPrincipal
```

This class can have the properties you'd like to reference (StaffID for example).

Thne you'll need to hook into the actual authentication process and assign the instance of your GenericPrincipal descendant to the "User" property.

Then each time you reference if you'll have to cast it to be your type in order to get access to the additional properties.

```
((MyPrincipal)User).StaffID
```

That's quite a bit more work as compared to what you've had to do so far.

But it's doable.

Comment: How would you "hook into the actual authentication process"? Do you mean in the ValidateUser method in MembershipProvider?

Comment: You'd implement the OnAuthenticate event in an HttpModule and do your stuff there. FYI - sticking with the ASP.NET provided authentication mechanism is better (in the long run) than doing something completely different. That is defining you own GenericPrincipal descendant and going down that route is better than completely avoiding it. The Membership provider is just one implementation of the ASP.NET built in mechanism. If it doesn't work for you, just implement your own. It'll pay off big time in the long run. ASP.NET/WCF applications the same infrastructure