# Getting current office id for user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my project once the user logs in they are assigned to an office and based on their office they only get information within that office. I want to get the current id of the user after logging in but i am not sure how to go about that or where to look. Any help or suggestions would be great.

asp.net mvc project.

Comment: Hi, it's not possible to help you unless you show some code and/or describe better what the officeId is and where is taken from and saved to...

Comment: Is the informaiton about their office stored in Active Directory, perhaps?  Or in a database somewhere?  Do you need to create a database or have your ITOps team start storing that data in AD?  (Really, we can't do much more to help ou at this point other than ask obvious questions.  You haven't given us much to go on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of your data store, you could use a similar approach to @Omar's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260697/how-can-i-reference-my-own-table-with-the-mvc-controller-user-property) I asked some time ago.

The basic idea is to define a parent/base Controller class from which all your relevant controllers inherit. Then, upon initializing that controller:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext) { }
```

You would setup the data based within the office. I can't describe this much further, because you haven't provided a lot of specifics, but within `Controller.Initialize` you would access this information via AD, your database, etc.

Finally, you could incorporate the retrieved data (via Repositories, etc) into your view models, or pass to the view using [ViewData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata.aspx) or [ViewBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). Though, I recommend the former over the latter in the interest of code cleanliness.